# Ruby's HTTP Client improperly parsing certain URLs

Tags: ruby, http, url, encoding

It is quite possible there is an answer to the following question, but if so, I am unable to recognize it.

Here's the thing: I am making a ruby program that is sweeping a dictionary for a list of all entries. I need that because I want to sweep each entry in search of specific words, but that's beside the point. The problem is that my program has trouble downloading data from certain encoded links, which has never occured before.

By encoded, I mean the encoding replacing non-ASCII characters etc., so that a link like this:
http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/a+%5Bauch+A%5D+%5BBuchstabe%5D.html
looks like this:
http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/a+%5Bauch+A%5D+%5BBuchstabe%5D.html

The funny thing is that while the above does not work, most of links DO work, for instance:
/deutsch-englisch/A+an+B+anpassen.html

I have tested random links and they all work, and my regex matches what it is supposed to match.

Here's the function I am using:

```
def getDataOverHttpGet(link, proxy = nil)
    link = URI.unescape(link)           # added only now
    http = HTTPClient.new(:agent_name => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0')
    http.proxy = proxy if proxy
    r = http.get(link)
    raise r.status.to_s if r.status != 200
    return r.body
end
```

Which worked fine until now. It has been suggested to me that the URLs might be escaped by http client, so I added the unescape thing. What I got in return was an empty string instead of the information my program generates for missing data (= failed match using regex). However, using URI.escape makes no change, so might just be the case. However, I have no idea what else I can try.

Also, all the strings in my program are always in UTF-8 (no BOM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling it with URI.parse, like so:

```
http = HTTPClient.new(:agent_name => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0')
http.proxy = proxy if proxy
r = http.get(URI.parse(link))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, seems to have no effect on the result—that prompted me to look into my code again and I found there's another glitch, works now. Cheers!